# NULL-free shellcode

Tags: assembly, x86, null, instruction-set, shellcode

I am trying to convert an assembly program I wrote into NULL-free shellcode.

However, I am unsure how to go about this for certain instructions.
Some of them (in Intel syntax) include:

```
push 0x1000
```

and

```
mov BYTE [eax],0x31
```

I want to avoid using thousands of `inc eax` instructions. I was thinking maybe something creative with `xor`-ing values, and for the second, maybe if there was a flag to set to make it take a constant of only 8 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
push 0x1000
```

If you can spare a register (and you don't mind clobbering the flags), how about something like:

```
xor eax, eax
inc eax
shl eax, 12
push eax
```

---

```
mov BYTE [eax],0x31
```

The zero here does not come from the constant, but from the addressing mode. Try:

```
xchg eax, ecx
mov BYTE [ecx],0x31
xchg eax, ecx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a value in memory that contains a `0` byte, you can't use it directly as an immediate operand for `push` or `mov`.  You can construct it in a register using special properties of the constant, or XOR it with something.  (Then `push eax`, or whatever spare register you used.)

```
    xor eax,eax      ; 2 bytes
    bts eax, 12      ; 4 bytes; eax |= 1<<12
```

```
    xor eax,eax      ; 2 bytes
    mov ah, 0x10     ; 2 bytes; eax = 0x10 << 8
```

Or `push` an already zeroed register and do a byte store of the non-zero byte, if you want to keep the zeroed register for later.  `push eax` / `mov byte [esp+1], 0x10`

We don't care about performance so partial-register merging isn't a problem, nor are store-forwarding stalls from a narrow store that's later reloaded with a dword load.

---

Constants within [-128, +127] of 0 (via push/pop) or another register (with LEA) can be constructed in 3 bytes

```
   push 12            ; 2 bytes, works for -128 .. +127
   pop  eax           ; 1 byte

   lea  ecx, [eax+127] ; reg+disp8 addressing mode.  ECX = 139
```

See also [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code#comment389324_132985)

---

**In general, without having special properties for the constant**, you can construct it in 2 instructions with an XOR, ADD, or SUB.  (Or LEA or whatever).  XOR is easiest to see that you're not going to create any zero bytes, just pick any constant that doesn't have the same byte in the same position as the value you want.  (It doesn't have to be same in each byte, e.g. `0x12345678` also works)

```
   mov  eax, 0x1000 ^ 0x55555555     ;  mov eax, 0x55554555
   xor  eax, 0x55555555              ; cancel out the constant
```

Since we used EAX, this assembles to two 5-byte instructions:

```
  b8 55 45 55 55          mov    eax,0x55554555
  35 55 55 55 55          xor    eax,0x55555555
```

**Without a spare register,**

```
  68 55 45 55 55          push   0x55554555       # 0x1000 ^ 0x55555555
  81 34 24 55 55 55 55    xor    DWORD PTR [esp],0x55555555
```

---

#### Avoiding a zero in the ModRM from a [eax] addressing mode

It's not just `[eax]`, it's using it with an AL or EAX source, or with an immediate instruction that uses `/0` [as extra opcode bits in the `/r` field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation/53976236#53976236).

[`mov r/m8, imm8` (`C6 /0 ib`)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) is one such instruction, so you can't use it with a plain `[eax]` addressing mode.  If you can offset the address, like `inc eax` / `[eax-1]`, that works.

**Use a different register for the address in the first place if you can**, otherwise there are various things you can do

```
 c6 00 31                mov    BYTE PTR [eax],0x31   # nope, ModRM=00

 b1 31                   mov    cl,0x31               # using another register for data
 88 08                   mov    BYTE PTR [eax],cl     # /r field = 1 for the CL source


 80 20 31                and    BYTE PTR [eax],0x31   # clear bits we don't want
 80 08 31                or     BYTE PTR [eax],0x31   # set bits we do want

 # use a different register temporarily as @user200783 suggested
 91                      xchg   ecx,eax
 c6 01 31                mov    BYTE PTR [ecx],0x31
 91                      xchg   ecx,eax   # presumably need to restore it, otherwise you'd have used another reg in the first place.


  # offset the address.
 40                      inc    eax
 c6 40 ff 31             mov    BYTE PTR [eax-0x1],0x31
 # 48                      dec    eax   # optional, if you want to restore it
```

A couple ideas that *don't* work:

```
 # halve the address (if it's known to be aligned by 2):
 d1 e8                   shr    eax,1
 c6 04 00 31             mov    BYTE PTR [eax+eax*1],0x31   # Nope, SIB = 00

 # write more bytes: nope: mov r/m32, imm32  also has a /0 as part of the opcode
 c7 00 31 11 11 11       mov    DWORD PTR [eax],0x11111131
```