# What does the /4 mean in FF /4?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, opcode

One site that I [commonly refer to](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/jmp.htm) for x86 documentation has a few instruction codes with a slash and a number. For instance, `jmp` near absolute indirect gives `FF /4`, whereas `jmp` far absolute indirect gives `FF /5`.

What do the `/4` and `/5` mean?

To run a quick little test, I attached to a 32-bit process, allocated a bit of memory and had the assembler insert `jmp dword ptr[0x12345678]`; the generated bytecode was `FF 25 78563412`. I understand the address endianess, but how does the `25` relate to `/4` or `/5`?

My guess is that I generated a `jmp` far, and that the `/5` meant there were five bytes as parameters (4 bytes for the address + 1 byte for `25`). I'm still confused as to where the `25` is coming from.

Comment: 4 or 5 are values for 3-bit field in the second byte (modrm) of the instruction.

Comment: You should refer to the official intel documentation instead. As Igor quoted that even has explanations, and it is, well, official too ;)

Comment: duplicates: [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976236), [x64 instruction encoding and the ModRM byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15511482)

Comment: @Jester I don't think there is a quick answer on the official intel doc, it may lie in the big chunk of explanation, but no worth that much time to look up. Thus it is what stack overflow is good for. For beginners or people who only wants a particular answer it makes not much sense to look up all the documentation. Sometimes people also need a little bit of instruction/help, you cannot give people a 500 page doc and tell them to search all over for just one single question, if it takes much less time to just ask other people

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the Intel Reference Manual, section "3.1.1.1 Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table":

> - **/digit** — A digit between 0 and 7 indicates that the ModR/M byte of the
>     instruction uses only the r/m (register or memory) operand. The reg field
>     contains the digit that provides an extension to the instruction's opcode.
> - **/r** — Indicates that the ModR/M byte of the instruction contains a register
>     operand and an r/m operand.

This notation is also usually mentioned in the various descriptions of the ModR/M byte, [e.g.](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm)

Comment: To note: that `25` in the example is the ModR/M byte.

Comment: Oh wow! That link is golden! So it definitely *is* a near jump.

Comment: The only thing I'm having issues understanding is `if PM64 and adsize=32, then effective address = [EIP+sdword]` - what is PM64? A quick google search gives bleak answers.

Comment: Years later, finally dug in: PM64 refers to "processor mode 64", or "long mode". Should be enough of a jumping off point.