# Intel x86 OP Code 0xFF

Tags: assembly, x86

I saw that for example opcode `FF 15` is for `CALL` on one example that I was looking online, but when I tried to follow that in instruction set reference manual, it says that `CALL` is for `FF /2`, `FF /3` etc.

So I was wondering, what this `/2`and `/3` represents?

Maybe it's mentioned somewhere in doc, but document is more than 2k pages, and not sure where to look for that.

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned in the doc. See section _"3.1 INTERPRETING THE INSTRUCTION REFERENCE PAGES"_, in particular section _"3.1.1.1 Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table"_ which says _"/digit -- A digit between 0 and 7 indicates that the ModR/M byte of the instruction uses only the r/m (register or memory) operand. The reg field contains the digit that provides an extension to the instruction's opcode."_

Comment: So, basically this `15` represent that extension to this `FF` opcode?

Comment: The `15` is the modr/m byte. Only the `reg` field is the extension the `r/m` is the operand. `reg` is `2` and `r/m` is `5` meaning `disp32`. See section _"2.1.5 Addressing-Mode Encoding of ModR/M and SIB Bytes"_

Comment: Thank you @Jester

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the /4 mean in FF /4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295464/what-does-the-4-mean-in-ff-4)