# Give the opcode and number of bytes of code for each of these instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, instruction-encoding

I am currently taking a low-level programming class and unfortunately, I cannot find this information in our text book (most of the questions are not contained in our text).  I am having a hard time determining how to solve these.  There is no information as to "CPU or anything along those lines".    The question is as follows:

> Give the op code and number of bytes of code for each of these instructions.
> (a) mov exc, 984           Op Code_____     Number of Bytes_____
> (b) xchg eax, ecx          Op Code_____     Number of Bytes_____

There are a lot more, but if anyone could help me understand how to do these two, I hope to be able to translate that to the other questions.

One thing I tried, but not sure what I am seeing: I created a small *.asm project in Visual Studio 2019 and added that one line of code in (a) and looked at the listing file.  I see it shows the following:

> ```
> 00000000  B9 000003D8         mov  ecx, 984
> ```

I am not sure if the information is to be found here and I am just missing it, or there is some other way to figure this out.

Comment: Refer to an instruction set reference for the encoding of x86 machine instructions.  Visual Studio gives you a disassembly, but it seems to show immediates as 32 bit numbers which may be a bit confused (i.e. you'd usually give the encoding of `mov ecx, 984` as `b9 d8 03 00 00` instead of `b9 000003d8`).  But the general approach is sound.  Assembling the instructions in question and then asking a disassembler for the encoding or looking at the listing is a good approach.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.  I appreciate the help and information :-)

Comment: @fuz: Is [tag:instruction-encoding] a new tag?  I've always just used [tag:machine-code] for questions like this; I'm not sure we need a separate tag for questions about how to encode instructions, although that is maybe a different kind of question from other machine-code questions that aren't about that basic thing.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's not a tag I made, I just found it searching for something that fits.

Comment: @fuz: Thoughts on making it a duplicate of [machine-code] (and [machine-language] if we eventually get it added as a synonym of machine-code)?  I think probably yes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not sure.  I think [instruction-encoding] is a lot more specific than [machine-code] and checking the question list for the latter, people seem to use it a lot just for questions about shuffling around text sections of binaries.

Comment: @fuz: Ah ok, if there are other major uses for [machine-code], other than how specific instructions are encoded / how machine code works, then yeah there's a use for having a separate tag.  We can add it or replace it on some of those [machine-code] Q&As.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you have questions about the encoding of instructions, check instruction references, like AMD's or [Intel's Manuals](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html).  Specifically, Volume 2 of Intel's manual applies here.  A web-browsable version like https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ is scraped from that PDF.

The full PDFs have intro chapters that explain the notation used in entries for individual instruction.  Related Q&As about that:

- [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation)
- [What does the /4 mean in FF /4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295464/what-does-the-4-mean-in-ff-4)  (Not relevant to the encoding of either of the specific instructions you asked about, but other instructions do the /r field as extra opcode bits).

---

For `xchg eax, ecx` we check the [`XCHG` section in the manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xchg). In the table there the instruction we want is `XCHG EAX, r32`. It's encoded as `90+rd` (`90` here is hexadecimal), where `rd` is a code that designates which double-word register is used.

Looking earlier in the manual (right at the beginning of the Instruction Set Reference chapters in the full PDF), we find the definition of `+rd`, and see that `ECX` has a value of `1`. The compact single-byte encoding of `xchg eax, ecx` is therefore `91` (again, hex).

It is also possible to assemble this as 2 bytes, which is what one specific online assembler did for me, but the fact that one of the operands is `EAX` allows for the 1-byte version.

---

For `mov ecx, 984` (I'm assuming `exc` is a typo) we check the `MOV` section, and find the instruction as `MOV r32, imm32` in the table there, encoded as `B8+rd id`. From the other one, we already know that the `rd` for `ECX` is `1`, so the first byte is `B9`.

Then we have `id`, and checking the same section where we found `+rd`, we know that that's a 4-byte immediate signed operand, given as low-order byte first (little endian). Converting `984` from decimal to hexadecimal, we get `3D8`. Encoded in 4 bytes as little endian, this is `D8 03 00 00`.

Putting it together, the encoded instruction is `B9 D8 03 00 00`.

---

(Fun fact: x86 registers are numbered in EAX, ECX, EDX, EBX, ESP, EBP, ESI, EDI.  The first 4 are not in alphabetic for what are probably [obscure historical reasons](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/why-are-first-four-x86-gprs-named-in-such-unintuitive-order).)

---

You can verify these by using any assembler, like NASM, and asking it to make a "listing".  Like `nasm -felf32 foo.asm  -l /dev/stdout` to print a listing on the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This explains the situation perfectly and I do appreciate the help