# Disp8 vs Disp32 for MOD_RM byte

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel, machine-code

In the MOD part of the MOD_RM byte, it has four values for what the mode can be:

- `11` - Uses a register
- `10` - 32-bit displacement
- `01` - 8-bit displacement

From here: http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0060_mod_reg_r_m_byte.htm

The examples it gives are:

```
MOD R/M Addressing Mode
=== === ================================
 00 000 [ eax ]
 01 000 [ eax + disp8 ]               (1)
 10 000 [ eax + disp32 ]
```

I'm not quite sure I understand the difference between a 32-bit and 8-bit displacement. What would the following be examples of?

```
# sorry this is using ATT syntax not Intel
movb $1, (%eax)
movw $1, 2(%eax)
movl $1, (%eax, %eax)
movq $1, 2(%eax, %eax)
movq $1, 2(%eax, %eax)
movq $1, 2(%rax, %rdi)
movq $1, 2(%rax, %rdi, 4)
```

is 32- and 8-bit the size of the second register used in the memory address? If so, why does it not include a 16- or 64- bit displacement in the `MOD` ?

Comment: They'd be examples of errors.  Did you even try assembling your example?  `(%eax, %al)` is not encodeable in any mode.  All registers in an addressing mode have to be the same size, and that size has to be 32 or 64 (in 64-bit code), or 16 or 32 in 16 or 32-bit code.  (Address-size prefix toggles to the non-default size).  Also, all of them are missing an operand-size suffix, so it's ambiguous with an immediate source and a memory destination.

Comment: @PeterCordes just updated it and verified it assembled.

Comment: Ok.  Anyway no, the displacement part of an address is the constant part, like an immediate.  In all of yours it's either empty or `2`, which fits in a disp8.  Look at the machine code (e.g. with `objdump -d`) and notice which parts of the source end up in bytes of code, and that there are 3 bytes of high zeros.  Unless you use a `{disp32}` GAS override like mentioned in [x86 XOR opcode differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50336269) that I linked in an answer to one of your previous questions.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html

Comment: [x64 instruction encoding and the ModRM byte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511698) quotes a table from the Intel manuals with footnotes that somewhat clarify what displacements are.