# Can a processor have same opcode for different sets of instructions?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, machine-code, instruction-set, opcode

I have a processor. Some instruction sets are AND, ADD, ANDI, ADDI. These looks like same but they are not. Can I assign same opcode for looks like same instructions sets as follows screen shot:

[image: Example of ISA]
or sixth bit is enough to differentiate them?

In actual example of ISA, I have 13 instruction sets (AND, ADD, LD, ST, ANDI, ADDI, CMP, JUMP, JE, JA, JB, JBE, JAE). Because of size of instruction sets, I think number of opcode bits should be 4 bits and also all different instruction sets should have different opcode like ADD 0001, ADDI 0010, AND 0011, and ANDI 0100 etc.

Comment: Yes, as long as you can differentiate you can do whatever you want. You don't have to use simple binary opcode.

Comment: Classic MIPS has the same "opcode" field for most R-type instructions, differentiating them with the `funct` field.  Same sort of idea here.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Most CISC CPU assembly languages do this actually. I'll use <del>6502 Assembly</del> x86 Assembly to illustrate, but it's certainly possible to write your own MIPS assembler that allows this.

```
    mov eax,[eax]  ;encoded as 8B 00
    mov eax,[ecx]  ;encoded as 8B 01
    mov eax,[edx]  ;encoded as 8B 02
    mov eax,[ebx]  ;encoded as 8B 03
```

All of these instructions load the `eax` register indirectly using another register as a pointer to memory. Which register is used depends on the pattern of bits. Not the best example, but it is a thing that many CPUs do.

EDIT: used x86 Assembly for the example now, which doesn't completely change the bytes when using different operation modes for this example.

Comment: All those different instructions have different opcode bytes.  The question is talking about machine-code instructions that have the same "opcode" field but are differentiated by other bits in the instruction word.  e.g. `add` vs. `addi`, if you look at the image they linked.

Comment: @PeterCordes Perhaps I misunderstood the question. I'll research a more relevant example but I feel like x86 does something like this with its Mod R/M table.

Comment: yeah, some x86 instructions share the same opcode byte, using the `/r` field as 3 extra bytes.  [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976236) / [x64 instruction encoding and the ModRM byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15511482).  Mostly immediates, which is why we only have `add r/m, imm`, not `add reg, r/m, imm`, only the 186 form of `imul reg, r/m, imm` works like that, with a whole opcode to itself so it can use both fields of ModRM for non-immediate operands so it can be non-destructive, like AVX.