# XMM register 0 not being used in Intel instruction documentation

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, sse

In the Intel x64 manual it says that there's XMM registers 0-7 in 32-bit SSE2 mode.  Why then do 95% of the instructions that use these registers skip 0 and use 1-4?

For example, Intel's vol.2 manual [entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/addps) for `addps` lists it as `ADDPS xmm1, xmm2/m128`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misunderstanding something, probably the placeholders in the manual. When an instruction description says `xmm1` or `xmm2` it usually means any xmm register, the number just indicates operand numbering.

For example, `ADDPS xmm1, xmm2/m128` can add two arbitrary xmm registers or add a memory operand to an arbitrary xmm register.

Comment: Whoa, major misunderstanding! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The numbering in Intel's manuals are **placeholders**, like first xmm operand, not register numbers.

---

Look at `blendvps` for one case where XMM0 is the only choice for one operand, not a placeholder, for the non-AVX version: https://felixcloutier.com/x86/blendvps.

| Opcode | Instruction | Op/En |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `66 0F 38 14 /r` | `BLENDVPS xmm1, xmm2/m128, <XMM0>` | RM0 |
| `VEX.128.66.0F3A.W0 4A /r /is4` | `VBLENDVPS xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m128, xmm4` | RVMR |
| `VEX.256.66.0F3A.W0 4A /r /is4` | `VBLENDVPS ymm1, ymm2, ymm3/m256, ymm4` | RVMR |

**Notice the all-caps `<XMM0>` inside angle brackets: That's what Intel writes when they mean a specific register is required.**  (Used implicitly in the machine code, like RDX:RAX for `mul rcx`)

Also notice the Op/En (**Operand Encoding**) column, which has a key for the other table, "Instruction Operand Encoding", where we can see the registers encoded by ModR/M (or VEX) fields, or even an immediate; `vblendvps` is kinda crazy.  But anyway, given that there are bits in the instruction to encode them, it's clear they can be any XMM register.

| Op/En | Operand 1 | Operand 2 | Operand 3 | Operand 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RM0 | **ModRM:reg (r, w)** | ModRM:r/m (r) | **implicit XMM0** | NA |
| RVMR | ModRM:reg (w) | VEX.vvvv (r) | ModRM:r/m (r) | imm8[7:4] |

The (r,w) vs. (w) or (r) tells you whether an operand is read, written, or both.

See also

- [x86_64 Opcode encoding formats in the intel manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440527/x86-64-opcode-encoding-formats-in-the-intel-manual)
- [How to determine if ModR/M is needed through Opcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312459/how-to-determine-if-modr-m-is-needed-through-opcodes)

---

Or read the earlier chapter of vol.2 that tells you how to read the entries: The operand-encoding table has the details of exactly how an instruction specifies registers. *[How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15017659)* notation has an answer quoting some of it, but the actual PDF has examples and stuff.