# x86_64 Opcode encoding formats in the intel manual

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

What are the "Op/En" formats listed in the [Intel x86_64 reference manual?](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~hunt/class/2017-spring/cs350c/documents/Intel-x86-Docs/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) 
For example in the [Add opcode](http://prntscr.com/oqulx4) I can take a guess at some such as "I" = Immediate, but is there a comprehensive list for these?

Comment: Yes, in the intro section of the vol.2 manual you're talking about, I think.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you are talking about section 2.1, I only see reference to how the whole instruction is encoded, not the meanings of the columns I showed in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intro sections of [Intel's vol.2 manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf) explain how to read each entry:

> **Section 3.1.1.4 Operand Encoding Column in the Instruction Summary Table**
>
> The “operand encoding” column is abbreviated as Op/En in
>   the Instruction Summary table heading. Instruction operand encoding
>   information is provided for each assembly instruction syntax using a
>   letter to cross reference to a row entry in the operand encoding
>   definition table that follows the instruction summary table. ...
>
> NOTES
>
> - **The letters in the Op/En column of an instruction apply ONLY to the encoding definition table
>     immediately following the instruction summary table.**
> - ...

**So they're just keys to the table that goes with each instruction.**  And no, Intel doesn't seem to document what they stand for, but it's pretty straightforward.

(Related: [How to determine if ModR/M is needed through Opcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312459/how-to-determine-if-modr-m-is-needed-through-opcodes))

---

Yes, the `I` stands for Immediate.

Explicit operands encoded with the ModRM byte are `M` or `R` for the `r/m` or `reg` fields.

`V` is the field encoded by VEX.vvvv or EVEX, giving such instructions a 3rd operand for non-destructive operations, or for 3-operand instructions like FMA.

[`vpblendvb xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m128, xmm4`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pblendvb) encodes the 4th operand with an immediate byte, and uses `RVMR` in to Op/En column.  See also [What kind of address instruction does the x86 cpu have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325275/what-kind-of-address-instruction-does-the-x86-cpu-have) - I think that might be the only x86 instruction with 4 separate explicitly-encoded operands, outside of AVX512's 3 + mask register.

[`vextractf128` and the AVX512 versions of it](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vextractf128:vextractf32x4:vextractf64x2:vextractf32x8:vextractf64x4) use `A` through `D` for rows of the table because the only distinguishing feature is the "tuple type" for scaled short-displacements and masking.  It would just be weird if they used MRI / MRI2 / MRI4 / etc.

---

[`(rep) movs`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq) uses `ZO` : all operands are implicit (DF, RSI, RDI, and the memory pointed-to by them), so probably that stands for Zero Operands.  (At least none that need to be encoded).

[`cdq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cwd:cdq:cqo) uses the same `ZO` so yeah it's probably "zero (explicit) operands"

x86 only has a few ways to specify *explicit* operands.

Comment: @Mdren: perhaps you're looking at an old PDF copy, or an old HTML extract of and Intel manual.  Or did you mean AMD's manuals?  The current Intel PDF (which documents modern x86 in general including x86-64 long mode) https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf and HTML extracts from it (like the ones I linked) all say `ZO`.  Unless they use `NP` in some other instruction I didn't look at?  But anyway, I assume that stands for No Parameters.