# Understanding Intel assembly instruction syntax from manual

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel

In [Intel Software Developer's Manual](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671200), Volume 2B, page 4-540, the assembly `RDPID` instruction is presented.

| Opcode/‌Instruction | Op/‌En | 64/32-bit Mode | CPUID Feature Flag | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F3 0F C7 /7 RDPID r32 | R | N.E./V | RDPID | Read IA32_TSC_AUX into r32. |
| F3 0F C7 /7 RDPID r64 | R | V/N.E. | RDPID | Read IA32_TSC_AUX into r64. |

and then **Instruction Operand Encoding**

| Op/En | Operand 1 | Operand 2 | Operand 3 | Operand 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R | ModRM:r/m (w) | N/A | N/A | N/A |

I am not familiar with the conventions adopted and, from the table, I can't understand the syntax of the instruction. The only thing I can guess is that the opcode is the same for 32 and 64 bit mode, so maybe the instruction is the same in both cases. Also, the instruction is read-only (maybe this is the `R` in `Op/En`).

But what about the rest? I tried

```
rdpid <destination_register>
```

and it seems to work. Also `CS.D` and `REX.W` are mentioned, which I don't know (and a search through the manual for `REX.W` was unuseful, I couldn't find an explanation). Why isn't Operand 1 the destination register? And what is `ModRM:r/m (w)`?

**So, the actual question**: which is the correct syntax for this instruction and how to get it from the information provided in the manual?

Comment: Operand 1 *is* the destination register.  Note the "ModRM.MOD = 011B" which means the R/M field encodes a register-direct mode, not a memory addressing mode.  See also [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976236) / [x64 instruction encoding and the ModRM byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15511482) / [x86\_64 Opcode encoding formats in the intel manual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57440527) / [How to determine if ModR/M is needed through Opcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55312459)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much for all the references, they are very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CS.D` is the `D` bit in the segment descriptor referenced by `CS`, indicating if this is a 16 or 32/64 bit code segment.  `REX.W` is the `W` bit in the `REX` family of prefixes (`40h` to `4Fh`) indicating 64-bit operand size.

The instruction is described as

```
F3 0F C7 /7    RDPID r32  (in 16/32 bit mode)
F3 0F C7 /7    RDPID r64  (in 64 bit mode)
```

The notation `/7` means “a modr/m byte with 7 in the reg field.”  The notation `r32` and `r64` means “a general purpose register of 32 or 64 bits respectively.”  From the “instruction operand encoding” table you can learn that this operand is encoded in the r/m field of the modr/m byte. Thus, in 32-bit mode you can e.g. use the instruction like this:

```
F3 0F C7 CF    RDPID ECX
```

and in 64-bit mode like this:

```
F3 0F C7 CF    RDPID RCX
```