# Why does `add cl, 2` print `80 c1 02` in x86 hex?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

Trying to narrow my question down so I can get past this hurdle. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664856/how-to-interpret-x86-opcode-map?noredirect=1#comment116568309_28664856) isn't helping me much.

I am running NASM to see what the output of assembly is in terms of hex.

```
test:
    @nasm -f macho64 test.asm
    @objdump -x86-asm-syntax=intel --full-leading-addr -d test.o
.PHONY: test
```

In there I have some stuff, one of which is this:

```
add cl, 2
```

It outputs as:

```
80 c1 02
```

Looking at the [Intel Manuals](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf), I go to the ADD section, where it shows this:

```
80 /0 ib
```

That looks close enough, the `80` is there, and the `ib` is my number `2` immediate value. But how to calculate this `c1` from the `/0`?

The docs say:

> **/digit** — A digit between 0 and 7 indicates that the ModR/M byte of the instruction uses only the r/m (register or memory) operand. The **reg** field contains the digit that provides an extension to the instruction's opcode.

My questions are:

1. Why did the assembler decide to put a ModR/M byte here?
2. What does "uses only the r/m (register or memory) operand" mean? What operand, is it saying it recognizes there is a register `cl` and an immediate `2`, and so it chooses `cl` because it is a register?
3. "The reg field contains the digit that provides an extension to the instruction's opcode." Hmm? What does this mean? All that I can about gather from this is, `/0` means it's the 0th register? That doesn't work out though, seems wrong.
4. Table 2-1 has the value `c1` in it, which aligns with the `cl` register under the "Effective Address" header. Don't know what that means though. The corresponding R/M bit is right there at `001`, and the column it's in is `0`. Though none of that means much to me yet.

How do I convince myself that this `c1` byte is correct? How do I read all the signs from the various tables, how could I deduce it myself from just looking at the assembly and the Intel tables?

Comment: Instead of [x86\_64 Opcode encoding formats in the intel manual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57440527), I should have linked [How to determine if ModR/M is needed through Opcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55312459).  That table from the vol.2 manual entry shows which asm-level operand is encoded exactly where in which part of the machine code.

Comment: Re: the `/0`: duplicate of [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976236) (my answer specifically addresses exactly what the `/number` means as opposed to `/r`.)

Answer (score 3):

1. Because the `Op/En` for the `80 /0 ib` says `MI` which says that Operand1 is in `MODRM:r/m`.
2. It means it's only using the "r/m" part of the modr/m and not the "reg" part.
3. Means the "reg" part contains a constant `0` as an opcode extension.
4. You look at the modr/m table 2-2, it has a heading row that says "/digit (Opcode)". So you pick the `0` column because of the `/0`. Then pick the `ECX/CX/CL/MM1/XMM1` row and voila, you got your `C1` value.

Comment: Okay point #4 is getting clearer, but I still don't understand points 2 and 3.

Comment: See figure 2-1 at the beginning of chapter 2.1. The `modr/m` byte consists of 3 fields, the `mod`, the `reg/opcode` and the `r/m`.  Some instructions use the `reg` to encode an additional register operand, other instructions like in your case, use it as an opcode extension.

Comment: How do you know this case uses it as an opcode extension?

Comment: The `/0` is defined to mean that. See section 3.1.1.1: _"/digit A digit between 0 and 7 indicates that the ModR/M byte of the instruction uses only the r/m (register or memory) operand. The reg field contains the digit that provides an extension to the instruction's opcode."_ Also, logically there is nothing to encode in the "reg" field - one of the operands comes from the `r/m` and the other is an immediate byte simply appended.

Comment: @LancePollard: [What does the /4 mean in FF /4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24295464) and an answer on [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15017659) both quote that part of the manual.  My answer on that last question explains what that's all about without quoting the manual, since another answer already just dumped that manual section.  So this info is kicking around on Stack Overflow already for future readers to find in answers, not just comments.