# How to encode an instruction when we just know the hex for opcode

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, instruction-encoding

In [this](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html) source, they have given that hex for cmp r/m16/32 imm8 is 0x837. Somewhere i got that, hex for ebp is 0b0101. With this information, how can i encode the instruction `cmp dword [ebp-4] 2`? I have been searching for this from a couple of hours and got no clues except for [this](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/bpetkov-x86-hacks.pdf)(page 61) similar instruction `cmpb $0xf,(%rdi)` encoded as 80 3f 0f. But I'm unable to understand this as the former source I mentioned says that 0x803 is for sbb. Also rdi is 0b0111 and not 0b1111 (which is r15 indeed). I'm getting confused... If possible, I want encoded instruction for both x86-32 and x86-64.

Comment: Note that the “hex” (resp. “opcode”) for `cmp r/m, imm8` is not `0x837`.  It's `0x83 /7`.  This is quite a different thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation you linked is not very useful unless you already know how the x86 instruction encoding works.  So let's try another one.  Following [this resource](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_35.html) (scraped from Intel's official PDF manuals<sup>1</sup>) we get the following candidate encodings:

```
81 /7 iw    CMP r/m16,imm16     Compare imm16 with r/m16.
81 /7 id    CMP r/m32,imm32     Compare imm32 with r/m32.
83 /7 ib    CMP r/m16,imm8      Compare imm8 with r/m16.
83 /7 ib    CMP r/m32,imm8      Compare imm8 with r/m32.
```

One thing to note here is that the same encoding is given both for word and dword operation.  This is not a mistake: the operand size is determined by the current code segment's default operand width (i.e. whether we are running in 16, 32, or 64 bit mode) and the presence of a `66` or `REX.W` operand size override prefix.  The rules are simple:

- in 16 bit mode, the default operand size is 16 bit
- in 32 and 64 bit mode, the default operand size is 32 bit
- the `66` prefix switches between 16 and 32 bit operand size
- in 64 bit mode, the `REX.W` prefix switches to 64 bit operand size

So when programming in 32 or 64 bit mode, no prefix is needed as the default operand size is already the one we want.

Now the question is whether to use `83` or `81`.  In this case, both can be used since our immediate fits into 8 bits signed.  We'll go ahead with the `83` opcode since the encoding is shorter.

The encoding `83 /7 ib` tells us that the opcode is `83` followed by a modr/m byte with reg = 7 (the other fields encode the r/m32 operand) followed by an 8 bit immediate.

The r/m32 operand `[ebp-4]` can be looked up in the modr/m byte table given in the reference you linked.  We have a memory operand with indexed addressing mode; index `ebp` and displacement `-4`.  The displacement fits into 8 bits signed, so we use the `[ebp+disp8]` entry in the table and end up at `7d` for the modr/m byte.  Following this comes the displacement byte, `0xfc` for −4 in two's complement.

Putting it all together we get `83 7d fc 02` as the encoding for `cmp dword ptr [ebp-4], 2`:

```
83  opcode
7d  modr/m byte: reg = 7, r/m = [ebp+disp8]
fc  displacement: -4
02  immediate: 2
```

Notably, the encoding is the same for 32 and 64 bit modes.  For 16 bit modes, extra `66` and `67` prefixes are needed to select a 32 bit operand and address size, giving `66 67 83 7d fc 02`.

---

**Footnote 1**:  In Intel's [Software Developer Manuals (SDM)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html#inpage-nav-2), the operand size attribute of instructions is described in volume 1 ch. 3.6, and the `66h` prefix to select the non-default one for the mode is described in volume 2 ch. 2.1.1 Group 3.

Other encoding details are mostly in the vol.2 manual.  Sites like https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ and https://c9x.me/x86/ are scraped from Intel's vol.2 PDF, but only include the entries for each instruction, not the intro stuff that tells you the basics that apply to every instruction, or how to read the details of the entries.  See also *[How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation)*

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In particular, I didn't understand the second byte. If the instruction had [esp-4] instead of [ebp-4], then I suppose the change happens only in that second byte. But I'm unable to figure out what does change.

Comment: `esp` is a special case because that requires a SIB byte as well. So you pick the `[--][--]+disp8` row which gives you modr/m of `7c` then the SIB table row scaled index `none` and column base `esp` gives you `24` so the complete instruction is then `83 7c 24 fc 02`

Comment: One small doubt, how to declare a section with read permission in nasm? if I write `section .custom exec write read`, it is giving `main.asm:139: warning: Unknown section attribute 'read' ignored on declaration of section '.custom'` error!

Comment: Because there is no `read` attribute. Consult the [manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.2).

Comment: Yup, thanks. It got executed correctly without read attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Consult the official *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z*, available on [Intel's website](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html) in several formats. Turn to the page about `CMP`, find the row with `CMP r/m32, imm8`. This gives the opcode column as `83 /7 ib`. Turn to
*Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte*. Pick the `[ebp]+disp8` row and the `/digit 7` column. The cell tells you the ModR/M byte is `7d`. You need to append the displacement of `-4` which is `fc` in 8 bit signed and your immediate operand. The complete instruction is thus `83 7d fc 02`. In 64 bit mode if you use `rbp` the encoding is the same. If you want to keep `ebp` you need to use an address size override prefix of `67`.