# ADD instruction forms, Intel manual doesn't describe operand size overrides like "byte" or "word"

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, intel

I'm looking at an example of Intel assembly being assembled by NASM. It has the instruction:

```
add byte [ebx], 32
```

How would I know from the documentation what "byte" does?

The book I'm reading explains in the text how "byte" tells the assembler that we're only writing a single byte to `ebx`. It's not clear to me how I'd know this from looking at the documentation.

From examples in the book and elsewhere, it looks like the `ADD` instruction has two forms:

1. `ADD <dest> <src>`
2. `ADD <size> <dest> <src>`

However, when I look at the Intel documentation[1], I don't see anything that looks like either of my forms.  Each of the instructions given in the table have only a single comma which, to me, makes it seem like all the corresponding opcodes take only two inputs. There is a table that gives "Instruction Operand Encoding".  Operands 3 and 4
NA.  Looking around the web, most sites don't mention anything about the size parameter (let alone if it applies to my processor).

I'm assembling on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU in 386 mode:

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs -o $OBJECTFILE $1
ld -m elf_i386 -o $BUILDNAME $OBJECTFILE
```

Maybe the instruction takes an extra operand for 386 but not for newer architectures?

---

[1] "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Combined Volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 3A, 3B, 3C, 3D, and 4", Vol. 2A 3-31 page 605 in the pdf.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html

Comment: It sets the operand-size attribute of the instruction in the asm source.  In machine code, that would be implied by the numeric opcode, or for 16/32/64-bit operand-size, by prefixes for the non-byte opcode.  Intel's manual documents the machine-code forms, not asm source syntax.

Comment: If you want to write a byte to the `ebx` register, that would be `add bl, 32`.  The form you show is not writing a byte "to `ebx`", but to memory where `ebx` refers (`ebx` is sourced not targeted).  There, `[ebx]` is a (memory) addressing mode, namely [register indirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Register_indirect_2).  Since one operand is a pointer to memory and the other a constant, the assembler doesn't know what size to put in the machine code, as either the memory operand or the constant could be 8, 16,or 32 in size: so that's where the `byte` annotation comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `byte` keyword in the asm source sets the operand-size attribute of the instruction.  In machine code, that would be implied by the numeric opcode, or for 16/32/64-bit operand-size, by the current CPU mode and prefixes for the non-byte opcode.  **Intel's manual documents the machine-code forms, not asm source syntax.**

See the following  re: how that gets encoded into machine code.

- [Is there a default operand size in the x86-64 (AMD64) architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289333/is-there-a-default-operand-size-in-the-x86-64-amd64-architecture)
- [How does x86 handle byte vs word addressing when executing instructions and reading/writing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628157/how-does-x86-handle-byte-vs-word-addressing-when-executing-instructions-and-read)
- [How to encode an instruction when we just know the hex for opcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904845/how-to-encode-an-instruction-when-we-just-know-the-hex-for-opcode)

---

**This is why assemblers have manuals, too, separate from the ISA manual.**

For example, NASM's manual, [Chapter 3: The NASM Language](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html)
*3.1 Layout of a NASM Source Line* describes the syntax layout of a mnemonic and operands.  Unfortunately that section neglects to mention the overrides you can put in front of operands, only the prefixes like `o16` you can put in front of the mnemonic!  (As a clunkier manual way to specify the operand-size.)

The manual does has examples of usage of operand-size overrides in multiple places, e.g. in [2.2 Quick Start for MASM Users](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.3) it points out that NASM needs `mov word [var], 2` even if var is `var dw 0` which in MASM would magically imply an operand-size for that instruction.  And mention of the same specifiers [when used with `strict`](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.7) to force the encoding of the immediate, not just the operand-size.  e.g. `add ecx, strict dword 123` forces the `add r/m32, imm32` form, while `add ecx, dword 123` still allows the `add r/m32, imm8` form.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add)

---

Some other x86 assemblers, like GAS and clang/LLVM, by default use [AT&T syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) that's very different from what Intel manuals use to talk about instructions, where operand-size is specified (if needed) by a suffix on the instruction mnemonic, like `movb $'a', (%rdi)` instead of MASM `mov byte ptr [rdi], 'a'` (note the extra `ptr` keyword) or NASM `mov byte [rdi], 'a'`

**Assembly syntax depends on the tool, not the ISA**.  Intel's manuals, especially vol.2, the part that lists every available instruction, do *not* specify the syntax details of how to specify operand-size in asm source when it would be ambiguous.

---

##### In asm source, a register can imply operand-size

For instructions where both operands must be the same size, a register operand implies the operand-size in asm source syntax, so you don't need to specify it.  e.g. `add eax, [rdi]` doesn't need to be `add eax, dword [rdi]`.

But mov-immediate to memory (or any other `op mem,imm` instruction)  are ambiguous, as are one-operand memory instructions like `inc [mem]`, and the rare instructions where operands don't have to be the same size like `shl [rdi], cl` (destination size could be b/w/d/q) or `movzx eax, [rdi]` (source size could be byte or word)

See [When do I need to specify the size of the operand in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324864/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-size-of-the-operand-in-assembly)

Good assemblers like NASM will error on that ambiguity.  Less-good assemblers will sometimes just pick a default. e.g. GAS picks dword for instructions other than MOV, e.g. `add $1, (%rdi)`, and only recently even added a warning about that!

Similarly, `[rdi + rax]` specifies 64-bit address-size, while `[edi + eax]` would be 32-bit address-size.  The default address-size (in asm source) for something like `[1234]` is the bitness of the current mode, i.e. not using a `67` address-size prefix in the machine code.

Again, this is 100% about asm source-level syntax.  Encoding an instruction into machine code for a certain mode necessarily implies an operand-size.

That's why you need to tell the assembler what mode the CPU will be decoding in.  e.g. with NASM `bits 32` if you're making a flat binary or switching modes in a bootloader.  Or more normally by assembling with `nasm -felf64` to make a 64-bit object file.  In that case, `bits 32` would let you put mismatched machine code into the wrong object file, instead of causing an error at assemble time from `push ebx` not being encodeable for 64-bit mode.