# machine code FF 25 should have 64-bit operand but actually only 32-bit is available

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code, opcode

I have some machine codes as follow:

`FF 25 CA 21 00 00`

I know it's a `JMP`'s opcode with Op/En set to M, which means there's a ModR/M byte after it.

`0x25` => `0x00100101`, so the `reg` is 0b100, and the opcode is actually `FF /4`. However, the only matching one in JMP opcode summary table is:

> FF /4 ---- JMP r/m64 ---- Jump near, absolute indirect, RIP = 64-Bit offset from register or memory

This means what follows the ModR/M byte should be a 64-bit operand. But I only have a 32-bit operand, `CA 21 00 00`.

Did I miss something? Give me some hints on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an *indirect* jump.  r/m64 is the operand-size for the pointer to load as data into RIP, not the number of bytes used to encode the address to load from, or the new RIP itself.

`25` is a ModRM that encodes a RIP-relative addressing mode, so the 4 bytes are a `rel32` for the `[rip+rel32]` addressing mode.

Check https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2 or any other convenient way to feed those bytes to a disassembler:

```
ff 25 ca 21 00 00   jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x21ca]
```

---

See also

- [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)
- [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation)

Comment: I found what you've said in chapter 3.7.5.1 of *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual*:
"RIP + Displacement ⎯ In 64-bit mode, RIP-relative addressing uses a signed 32-bit displacement to calculate the effective address of the next instruction by sign-extend the 32-bit value and add to the 64-bit value in RIP."